# Read 8 Bit Binary Numbers from text File in C

Tags: c, file, parsing, text

I'm trying to read from a text file in C that contains a list of 8 bit binary numbers to be used in another function.

```
The text file is formatted like:
01101101
10110110
10101101
01001111
11010010
00010111
00101011
```

Ect. . .

Heres kinda what i was trying to do

Pseudo code

```
void bincalc(char 8_bit_num){ 
//does stuff 
}

int main()
{
    FILE* f = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    int n = 0, i = 0;
while( fscanf(f, "%d ", &n) > 0 ) // parse %d followed by a new line or space
{
    bincalc(n);

}

fclose(f);
```

}

I think i'm on the right track, however any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just read the whole lines (`fgets` or `fscanf(f, "%s...)`), and then parse them on by one.

Comment: Your suggestion will not work. A decimal number read this way is *far* larger than can be stored into a `char`, you can only store at most three "buts" this way. Parsing a *decimal* as binary is possible but it may be easier to just parse the actual characters, as a string.

Comment: the code is reading a int (4 bytes) and the bincalc function is expecting a char (1 byte) suggest convert the input to a char by reading 8 characters and compressing them into one char of 8 bits then calling the bincalc function with the result of that compression

Comment: @user3629249: ... but of course then there is nothing left to do in that function ...

Answer (score 0):

This is not the standard track to do it, but it ok. You are scanning the file reading `int`s so it will read the string and interpret them as decimal number, which you should in turn convert to the *corresponding* binary, i.e. converting 1010 decimal to 2^3+2^1=9 decimal. This is of course possible, you just need to *transform* powers of ten to powers of 2 (1.10^3+0.10^2+1.10^1+0.10^0 to 1.2^3+0.2^2+1.2^1+0.2^0). Be careful that this work with 8-bits numbers, but not with too huge ones (16-bits will not).

The more common way is to read the strings and decode the strings directly, or read char by char and make an incremental conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a number at the end, I would suggest something like the following:

```
int i;
char buf[10], val;
FILE* f = fopen("test.txt", "r");

while( ! feof(f) ) {
  val = 0;
  fscanf(f, "%s", buf);
  for( i=0; i<8; i++ )
    val = (val << 1) | (buf[i]-48);
  /* val is a 8 bit number now representing the binary digits */
  bincalc(val);
}

fclose(f);
```

This is just a short snippet to illustrate the idea and does not catch all corner cases regarding the file or buffer handling. I hope it will help anyway.

Comment: feof() is not valid until after trying to read past the end of the file.  In general, never use feof to control a loop  the rest of this answer looks good

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a possible solution, i made it simple so you can understand and adapt to your needs. You only need to repeat this for each line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   FILE *file =fopen("data","r");
   char *result=calloc(1,sizeof(char));
   char line[8];
   int i=0;

   for(;i<8;i++)
   {
      char get = (char)getc(file);
      if(get == '0')
         *result <<= 1;
      else if(get == '1')
         *result = ((*result<<1)|0x1) ;
   }

   printf("->%c\n",*result);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to specify binary format for `fscanf()` but you can convert a binary string like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fatal(char *msg) {
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    exit (1);
}

unsigned binstr2int(char *str) {
    int i = 0;
    while (*str != '\0' && *str != '\n') {   // string term or newline?
        if (*str != '0' && *str != '1')      // binary digit?
            fatal ("Not a binary digit\n");
        i = i * 2 + (*str++ & 1);
    }
    return i;
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned x;
    char inp[100];
    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = fopen("test.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        fatal("Unable to open file");
    while (fgets(inp, 99, fp) != NULL) {
        x = binstr2int(inp);
        printf ("%X\n", x);
    }
    fclose (fp);
    return 0;
}
```

File input

```
01101101
10110110
10101101
01001111
11010010
00010111
00101011
```

Program output

```
6D
B6
AD
4F
D2
17
2B
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the file line by line, then use [`strtol()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtol/) with base `2`.

Or, if the file is guaranteed to be not long, you could also read the full contents in (dynamically allocated) memory and use the `endptr` parameter.